# MS SQL Grouping with two table on Date field

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I am trying to grouping and retrieving data from two tables which are connected through data fields. Output is year and month wise from both the tables.
When i am making a join with another table 'purch_ret_hd', result is not correct for column Purchase_Return. Please suggest if something is wrong in query

```
Select YEAR(grn_hd.grn_date) AS GRN_Date,    
       DATENAME(MONTH,grn_hd.grn_date) AS Month_Name, 
       Month(grn_hd.grn_date) AS Month,     
       SUM(grn_hd.inv_amt) AS Purchase_Gross,  
       SUM(grn_hd.disc_amt) AS Purchase_discount,   
       SUM(grn_hd.inv_amt) - SUM(grn_hd.disc_amt) AS 
       Purchase_After_Discount,     
       sum(grn_hd.net_amt) AS Purchase_Net,   
       SUM(purch_ret_hd.net_amt) AS Purchase_Return 
FROM grn_hd   
LEFT JOIN purch_ret_hd
ON YEAR(purch_ret_hd.entry_date) = YEAR(grn_hd.grn_date) AND 
Month(purch_ret_hd.entry_date) = Month(grn_hd.grn_date)
AND purch_ret_hd.loc_id = grn_hd.loc_id 
AND purch_ret_hd.loc_id = grn_hd.loc_id 
GROUP BY     
YEAR(grn_hd.grn_date),Month(grn_hd.grn_date),
DATENAME(MONTH,grn_hd.grn_date)
Order by 1,3
```

Comment: 1. Please explain 'not correct' in more detail; 2. Please edit the query so that it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Please not that the column "DATENAME(MONTH,grn_hd.grn_date) as Month_Name") appears twice, but the first one is not written correctly ("**eATENAME**(MONTH,grn_hd.grn_date) AS Month_Name")

Comment: You just fixed it. So my answer is not relevant anymore.